# How can I make GCC and VS compilers agree on `typename` keyword?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, c++17

Is there a Visual Studio (2019) build setting I can change to make the first line below fail to compile when I neglect to put the `typename` keyword.  Because GCC keeps complaining that it's required and won't build without it.

```
auto v = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T::element_type>(sp);         // Builds in VS, fails in GCC
auto v = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<typename T::element_type>(sp);// Builds in both VS and GCC
```

Note:

- `sp` is `shared_ptr<Base>`
- `T` is `shared_ptr<Derived>`
- `Derived` derives from `Base`

I've already got the VS language standard set to C++17 (`/std:c++17`) the warning level set to 4 (`/W4`) and full compatibility turned on  (`/permissive-`).  But Visual Studio still lets that line pass.  GCC (version 10.3 set to build as C++17) will not compile due to the missing `typename`

I don't care which compiler is right about the keyword still being required.  The point is that it's legal, whether it's superfluous or not.  I just want to force them to agree on the topic via build switches if possible.

So alternately, if that keyword is no longer truly required according to the C++ 17 standard going forward, then is there GCC build setting I can flip to allow the line of code to pass without the keyword?

[EDIT]

I'm adding a minimal reproducible example here.  Apologies for not putting it in initially but I was mostly asking for a compiler flag or something so I figured it wasn't necessary.  The following code builds just fine on VS 2019 16.11.3 with the compiler settings I mentioned.  It is admittedly contrived but I adapted it from the actual code which is pretty hairy...

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public :
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
};

using BasePtr = std::shared_ptr<Base>;

class Derived : public Base
{
};

using DerivedPtr = std::shared_ptr<Derived>;

template<class T> 
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<T, BasePtr>::value, T>::type
getAsT(BasePtr sp)
{

    const auto out = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T::element_type>(sp); 

    if (nullptr == out)
        throw std::runtime_error("Not the right type");

    return out;
}
int main()
{
    auto derived = std::make_shared<Derived>();
    auto derived2 = getAsT<DerivedPtr>(derived);
}
```

Comment: whats the issue with `// Builds in both VS and GCC` ?

Comment: Because I keep forgetting it and checking in code without it.  I break the nightly build and then I have to go fix it.  I've been living with that for a while now and I can go on living with it but I'd like to find a way to eliminate the possibility of this happening by making them agree at compile time

Comment: Did you already check how clang behaves concerning this? (I wouldn't wonder if it's with gcc.) So, you could add a tool chain with clang to check this in Windows / Visual Studio before checking in. (I've no real idea for a better work flow. I'm used to check my code base in a Debian in a VM but as well as you I often forget to do this _before_ committing...)

Comment: i am still not sure if I understand the question. Are you looking for a msvc flag that makes it complain about missing `typename` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes.  Either an MSVC flag that makes MSVC complain  or a GCC build flag that makes GCC *not* complain.  As long as it's language legal

Comment: Try compiling use the `/Za` flag?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=msvc-160

Comment: could you provide a [mcve]? I didnt manage to get an example where msvc did not complain

Comment: @Scheff'sCat No I'm afraid I have no familiarity with clang.  It's long been one of those "I've been meaning to read up about it" items in a long list.  But I will make that a priority if you think that might help

Comment: @RichardCritten I believe the OP is fully aware of this. But how can MSVC be convinced to **not** to accept the `auto v = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T::element_type>(sp);` because it's the only compiler which doesn't complain about this. (As suspected, clang doesn't accept it as well as gcc.)

Comment: @RichardCritten the problem op is trying to solve is that there is no error with msvc for this: https://godbolt.org/z/n38hP5r9d

Comment: @RichardCritten MSVC is known (at least, to me) to be very sloppy especially concerning templates. It does accept a lot of things which "bounce" in gcc and clang. So, if VS is your primary IDE, a lot of minor issues will slip in and you won't recognize until you cross-check in another compiler. In the case of OP, this is a gcc (probably from a CI/CD chain). Hence, he accidentally commits things which were running in VS but break the nightly build with gcc (on the git server). He's tired of this and looks for a solution to this misery...

Comment: Disclaimer: I noticed (and appreciated) that the quality of MSVC has improved much over the recent years.

Comment: I've added a test app I whipped up from the actual code.  I just built it locally with the same settings as my production app (need to start using godbolt, I guess...)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately even with the /Za flag, it still builds

Comment: @Joe The Compiler Explorer is a handy tool for issues like yours. (I once used it to find out about the sense of the `/permissive-` option of MSVC: [Compiler Explorer: Conformance Test](https://godbolt.org/z/EG6dEW).) ;-)

Comment: FWIW, there is a [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html) (P0634) that was accepted in C++20 that relaxes the rules on where typename is required.  This might be something that MSVS just implements, regardless of the language standard chosen.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of private (i.e. myself only) clang step is the way to go then.  I don't want to saddle other developers with longer build times since I'm the primary culprit. 
 Thanks for all the info.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat not surprisingly MSVC passes with `/std:c++latest`

Comment: @NathanOliver: C++20 still requires it in this case (even if the template parameter is known to be a type).

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a copy of Visual Studio to hand to experiment with, so I'm going to make some generic suggestions. (don't shout at me, I'm trying to be helpful)

Firstly, this might not be something the compiler should deal with. Language checks can be done with a static analyzer. Visual Studio has a built-in static analyzer. You could try turning it on and searching for rules related to "typename" follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/code-analysis-for-c-cpp-overview?view=msvc-160)

A similar technique that will definitely work is to install a "clag-tidy" [plug-in for visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/clang-tidy?view=msvc-160), of which there are a few to choose from. In general, if clang-tidy can parse your code, GCC will work too.
You can often map clang-tidy to run on a key press, or even on saving a file.

Sorry if this is not specific enough, but I hope it gives you a few options.

Comment: it is something the compiler should deal with, because pedantically `typename` is required

Comment: According to MS,  "In template definitions, provides a hint to the compiler that an unknown identifier is a type. ". They may be wrong, but hint rarely implies required.
When I posted my suggestion, I knew that it would attract flak, which is why I said "don't shout at me".
 Which is easier? Convincing MS to produce a perfect compiler, or to use a static analyzer pass to enforce specific rules not related to the code produced?
My answer has the advantage of actually being useful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/typename?view=msvc-160

Comment: Analyzer does not complain about my code, unfortunately.  Will look into clang-tidy.  I'm reluctant to add an extra build step for all developers so and it looks like that might be the way to go

Comment: colloquially it is a "hint", because there are many contexts where in principle it could be left out without creating ambiguity. Nevertheless it was required and when left out it is an error (I think rules have changed or will change, but afaik not till C++17).